# I want to find event1 in my EEG data, followed by event2 and then extract reaction time between them

Tags: eeg, reaction-time

```
for i=1:length(subjects)
    EEG = pop_loadset([sub_name{i},'.set'],folder);
    for k = 1:length(EEG.event)-1
        disp(k);
        if strcmp(EEG.event(k).type,con1)
            k = k+1;
            if strcmp(EEG.event(k+1).type,con2)
                rt = EEG.event(k+1).latency-EEG.event(k).latency;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome. What are the events? How are they defined and what are their characteristics? More general information helps too -  What was the experiment like? How many channels? What was the task, if any?

Comment: Thanks. There were two types of stimulus.stimulus1 followed by a response with no time limit. hence I have now data with 36 type1  stimulus,followed by their responses and same for type stimulus2. Total channels were 32. I am interested in retrieving the shortest reaction time between type1 stimulus and the response (same for type2 stimulus) and epoch the events based on this reaction time.

Comment: And you know when these events happened? Or do you have to analyze the data to extract them?

Comment: No I don't know when these events happened. But for every event I have a trigger, based on them I need to extract event1 followed by its response and difference between their reaction time.

Comment: This seems like more of a programming question, or a specific research question we can't really answer here: you need to decide what your response is before bothering to try to detect it.

Comment: I agree with @BryanKrause - I am still uncertain what the bottle neck is in your analysis. As of now, according to the comment, it seems like a simple trigger time extraction problem, linking them to a time stamp and subtract the two?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using Matlab. Your code is mainly sound, but a few comments:

- don't use "i" or "j" as they are function names in Matlab.
- don't change the value of a for loop variable inside the loop.

Here is you code, corrected:

```
for sub=1:length(subjects)
    EEG = pop_loadset([sub_name{sub},'.set'],folder);
    trial = 0;
    for eve = 1:length(EEG.event)
        if strcmp(EEG.event(trial).type,con1)
            trial = trial+1;
            trialonset(trial) = EEG.event(trial).latency;
        elseif strcmp(EEG.event(trial).type,con2)
            trialoffset(trial) = EEG.event(trial).latency; 
        end
    end
    rtlist{sub} = trialoffset-trialonset;
end
```